# Java Servlet redirect to calling jsp page

Tags: servlets

I wish to redirect my servlet to calling jsp page.
Though i got many jsp pages calling same servlet I cannot specify a specific jsp location in request.sendRedirect() method of servlet.

So how do I do it??

Comment: what you tried to do?

Comment: I call the servlet from jsp form and then get back reply from servlet using response.redirect(JSP FILE NAME). However as I got more than 1 jsp files doing same thing I cant use response.redirect method of servlet which is specific to 1 jsp file I want reply back to each individual calling file